# How to use validation summary for particular button in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validationsummary

I have a page with controls as shown below,

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt_name" runat="server"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
 ControlToValidate="txt_name"
 ErrorMessage="Name"
 Text="*"
 runat="server"/>    
<asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button id="b2" Text="Clear" runat="server"/>
<asp:ValidationSummary
 HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
 DisplayMode="BulletList"
 EnableClientScript="true"
 runat="server"/>
```

How can I use validation summary only for Submit button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [CausesValidation = "false"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Clear button.

Using `CausesValidation`

```
<asp:Button id="b2" Text="Clear" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
```

By using this the button `b2` won't trigger validation.

In the second approach you can use the `ValidationGroup` property on each control which you want to include in the validation.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt_name" runat="server"ValidationGroup="check"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
 ControlToValidate="txt_name"
 ErrorMessage="Name"
 Text="*"
 runat="server"/>    
<asp:Button id="b1" Text="Submit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="check"/>

<asp:Button id="b2" Text="Clear" runat="server"/>
<asp:ValidationSummary
 HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
 DisplayMode="BulletList"
 EnableClientScript="true"
 runat="server"/>
```

This will work as I have been using the same approach.